# Integration with respect to a signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a singed measure, $f\in C_c(X)$, I want to show

$$\int fd(c\mu) = c \int fd\mu, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$$

Since $c\mu$ is also a singed measure, I think by definitionm I need to show  $$\int fd(c\mu)^+-\int fd(c\mu)^- = c \int fd\mu^+-c \int fd\mu^-$$

But I think here I can't directly say $d(c\mu)^+=cd\mu^+,d(c\mu)^-=cd\mu^-$, since the definition of $\mu^+,\mu^-$ involves $|\mu|$ and $|c\mu|=|c||\mu|$, hence I need to discuss wether $c<0$ or $c>0$ or $c=0$.

For example, $c<0$, then $$(c\mu)^+=\frac{1}{2}(|c\mu|+c\mu)=-c\mu^-$$$$(c\mu)^-=\frac{1}{2}(|c\mu|-c\mu)=-c\mu^+$$
Hence the LHS equals to the RHS since $\int fd(c\lambda) = c \int fd\lambda, \forall c >0$ when $\lambda$ is a measure.

Since I am new to this subject, could you help to confirm whether my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct, I assume that you used the following line of reasoning: if $c<0$ then
$$
  (c\mu)^+ = \frac12(|c\mu|+c\mu) = \frac12|c|(|\mu|-\mu) = |c|\mu^- = -c\mu^-.
$$
Alternatively, you could go via the decomposition of the state space into positive and negative sets.

Comment: The reason for $|c\mu|=|c||\mu|$ is the definition of variational measure, am I correct?

Comment: @JohnZHANG: for sure it is, as much as $\int_a^b f'(x)\mathrm dx = f(b) - f(a)$ follows from the definition of derivatives and Riemann integral. The question is, which facts are you allowed to use. For example, you shall feel free to use everything you can prove yourself. Can you show that $|c\mu| = |c||\mu|$?

Comment: Yes, I can. It's the first time I learn measure theory, and I am a little nervous and unconfident about my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnZHANG: sure thing, feel free to lurk here for the answer or check whether there were similar questions. General measure theory is rather neat and often intuitive things turn out to be true, for example it's much easier to deal with the Lebesgue integral that Riemann ones (to my personal taste).

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement.